# Asymptotic expansion of integrals of the form $\int_{\mathcal{D}} \exp(\lambda\, \phi(x))\, g(x) \,dx$ for small $\lambda.$

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

In the limit $\lambda\to\infty$ the asymptotic expansion of integrals of the form $\int_{\mathcal{D}}\exp(\lambda\,\phi(x))\,g(x)\,dx$ (where $\mathcal{D}\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ denotes the domain of integration and $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure) can be evaluated using the Laplace's method or the saddle point method. Are there any methods to find asymptotic expansion of such integrals in the limit of small $\lambda$ ? I am specifically interested in the case where the integrals $\int_{\mathcal{D}}(\phi(x))^n\,g(x)\,dx$ do not converge, so that simple expansion in $\lambda$ doesn't work.

Comment: I guess there is no good method, in quantum field theory one would do \int [D\phi] exp(S+J\phi) In which S contains \lambda that being perturbative term. In this case the integral \int \phi^n g dx do diverge and this problem was solved by renormalization.

Comment: I asked about a special case of this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/383592/5531), where $\phi(x) = -x^2$ and $g(x)$ is periodic.